# How to programmatically add header on UICollectionView with UICollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UICollectionView` in one of my `viewcontroller`. My collection view uses a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` (custom) to layout the cells. First thing, as soon as I select Layout as Custom in dropdown on Storyboard, option to select supplementary views goes away.

I tried doing that programatically as shown below, but none of the delegate methods are getting called.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (reusableview==nil) {
            reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
          }

        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recipe Group #%li", indexPath.section + 1];
        [reusableview addSubview:label];
        return reusableview;
      }
    return nil;
  }

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGSize headerSize = CGSizeMake(320, 44);
    return headerSize;
  }
```

In my viewDidLoad Method I have

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
```

Can anyone point me where I'm messing up?

Comment: have you set delegate to collection view ? -- `collectionView setDelegate:` -- `collectionView setDataSource:`

Comment: Yes, datasource is set. All other datasource methods are being called.

Comment: Should not be adding the label each time.  You will end up with labels on top of labels.  Will need to subclass with the label as a property, or set it in the if statement if it's going to be static.

Comment: Since you are already registering the `supplementary header view` , you can skip  if `(reusableview==nil)` block

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the issue, I was not returning attributes of my header in this UICollectionLayoutView method:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect; // return an array layout attributes instances for all the views in the given rect
```

Answer (score 18):

You're passing in the incorrect view kind.

Your line registering the class:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class]
  forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter
  withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
```

Should be:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class]
  forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
  withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
```

**Edit**: Looks like your code is all using sectionFooter. Are you trying to programmatically add a header or a footer?

Comment: I was trying to add both, but none worked. The delegate methods are not even getting called. (I updated the question though)

Comment: @ManishAhuja You mentioned you have a custom layout, does it implement layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath: ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But that's also not being called.

Answer (score 8):

Check that you gave reference size for header in UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
[flowLayout setHeaderReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(320, 50)];
```

and for footer

```
[flowLayout setFooterReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(320, 50)];
```

Comment: These methods are only available for UICollectionViewFlowLayout, and not for UICollectionViewLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Your delegate method for header reference size is wrong, you call footer method,**referenceSizeForFooterInSection**, as follow：

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  CGSize headerSize = CGSizeMake(320, 44);
  return headerSize;
}
```

Individually set HeaderReferenceSize will fix the header problem. But app will crash you keep the above method and return nil in **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind** for Footer.

Answer (score 0):

your check:

```
if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter)
```

Your should check for: `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`

same for:

`dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call this in your `viewdidload` method:

```
[collectionViewFlowLayout setHeaderReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 50)];
```

Comment: He is asking about simple UICollectionViewLayout, not flow